# React App is not behaving correctly on firefox and working fine on Google chrome

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0

Our application can log in successfully against Auth0 with Chrome, but when the user is on Firefox, the process turns into an infinite loop, bouncing back and forth between Auth0 and our website. If the user goes into the Firefox browser settings and puts the Auth0 url into the Cookie exception list with the Allow flag, then login works.

What setting do we need to change, server side, to allow the login process to work, without forcing users to make this local setting change? Can this be accomplished by making a change in the Auth0 server settings, or do we need to handle it separately from each application? Thank you.

I think there is cookie issue I am getting this warning in Mozilla firefox
`Cookie “_co%2Fverifier%2Fhttps%253A%252F%252Fauth.shkdev.org%2FbZlN8puf3j3L_compat” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite`

`cookieUtils.setCookie('redirectTo',`https://${subdomain}.${process.env.REACT_APP_DOMAIN}`, moment().add(1, 'day').utc()) cookieUtils.setCookie('keepRedirectionCookie', 'true', moment().add(1, 'day').utc())`

Here is how I am setting the cookie while logout, I can successfully able to logout from chrome but I am not able to logout from Mozilla firefox.